# NPM and Yarn install fail on package "@react-native-commuity/slider"

Tags: react-native, npm, package, expo, yarnpkg

I tried to install the package "@react-native-commuity/slider" in my project, but with NPM and Yarn install, I get a 404 error:

[image: NPM error]

[image: Yarn error]

I tried to check the URL link but it returns a 404 not found. What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake in the package name. Try this

```
yarn add @react-native-community/slider
```

or

```
npm install @react-native-community/slider
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that package has been deprecated and they recommend using a [community package](https://reactnative.directory/?search=slider) instead